# Device Orientation API not working with local webserver

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, orientation

While working with the [Device Orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) I noticed something strange.

The following online demo works perfectly (except for "compassneedscalibration"): https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html

But when I clone the [Soucecode](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/HTML5-API-demos.git) locally and provide the [Web page](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/HTML5-API-demos.git) via a local Web server<sup>*</sup> the API seems to not be available anymore. Although using the same browser tab. Also no Messages, warnings or errors appear in the JavaScript console.

The Web page states:

> deviceorientation event not supported
>   devicemotion event not supported
>   compassneedscalibration event not supported
>   [image: Screenshot of non working Webpage]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an intended behavior or a bug?
I will need to provide my web app by a local web server.

I am using "Chrome 79.0.3945.93" on "Android 7.1.1;VNS-L21 Build/NMF26V"

<sup>*)</sup> `python3 -m http.server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you need to provide the wep page via an Encrypted HTTPS connection on order to access the Device Orientation API and also some mediaDevices.

A simple way of providing HTTPS pages during development (not production) is this simple python webserver:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Based on http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/

# generate server.xml with the following command:
#    openssl req -new -x509 -keyout key.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes
# run as follows:
#    python3 simple-https-server.py
# then in your browser, visit:
#    https://localhost:4443


import http.server
import ssl
import os

directory_of_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#server_address = ('localhost', 4443)
server_address = ('', 4443)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                               server_side=True,
                               certfile=os.path.join(directory_of_script, "server.pem") ,
                               keyfile=os.path.join(directory_of_script, "key.pem"),
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this saved me tons of time!

If you use something like xampp to host locally, https should already be set up, so just type https instead of http and everything starts working.